# Will PHP sleep function slow down my site

Tags: php, email, cron, sleep

I’m looking at ways to send out 1 email every 1 min. I’ve looked at the example below [where the top answer is to use PHP `sleep()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877692/how-to-echo-something-every-4-minutes-while-in-an-endless-loop).

However, I’ve also [found suggestions that sleep() might slow down the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376941/sleep-function-uses-server-resources).

I’m not looking for exact answers but general approaches would be great.

Comment: See Vlads answer in the second topic you linked. Don't use sleep. You can come up with a more elegant solution than that by using your greatest asset, your brain. a job queue or a cronjob that executes every 4 minutes would be ideal. you can store pending jobs in your database, then the cron or job queue can read from that list of pending actions.

Comment: i assume your limiting the mail sending as your host limits you from sending more mail- wouldn't it be a better idea to change to an account that allows you to send the mail volumes you need, or a seprate mail sending service

Comment: i still think thats a 'hack' to get around a limit

Answer (score 3):

> However, I've also found suggestions that `sleep` might slow down the
>   server.

Yes, and hitting the `pause` button on a movie playing on your computer will slow down the duration of the film based on the amount of time you `pause` the movie.

The purpose of [`sleep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) is to put a pause in your script. As described in [the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php):

> Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.

So yes, it slows down your server. But only on content or pages where `sleep` is active.

So if this is a fronted script with `sleep` in it, it slows down the ability for anyone to view content via the PHP script that uses `sleep`.  Place it in the middle of a page where HTML is rendering with a 1 second delay & your page now takes 1 second longer to render.

If this is a backend process only you really know about or trigger, no big deal. It’s a background process anyway so it will just expectedly slow things down in that realm.

That said, let’s look at your core question which is the first sentence of your post:

> I’m looking at ways to send out 1 email every 1 min.

Then what you are looking for is a [`cron`](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) job which is a timed job on a Unix/Linux system. An entry for a `cron` job for something sending mails out every minute might be something like this:

```
* * * * * /full/path/to/php /full/path/to/your/php/script.php
```

But that is superficial. It basically just triggers the `script.php` every minute. Then within your `script.php` you would have to create some core logic that would control what happens each time it’s triggered. If you are using a database, then maybe you could create a `last_sent` field where you sent a time stamp of the last time a mail was sent to a recipient and then you act on that. But again, the logic is based on your core needs.

But at the end of the day, I am not too clear how `sleep` would factor into any of this. Might be worth it to take a step back and better architect your script to fit your needs knowing what `cron` is, what `sleep` is & what they are as well are not.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally done with a separated worker and a queue manager.

That's it: you have a queue manager (i.e. RabbitMQ) that a sending email worker is bound to,

Then when you need to send 10 emails you put all of them to the corresponding queue at once in the script that serves HTTP response. This step is immediate.

Then a worker reads emails one by one and sends them with required delay. This step takes some time but we don't care.